# How can I minimise ping time when streaming to Twitch via OBS?

Tags: league-of-legends, networking, streaming

The last time I tried streaming, my ping for League of Legends would jump from ~34 to 60-180. I have since upgraded both my service, router, and modem to newest models, and constructed a new computer.

This has dropped my ping substantially however not entirely, I still receive anywhere from 39 to ~60 ping. This is playable but still not optimal, and hardware issues are not the problem.

speedtest.net puts my download speed at 33.48 mbps and upload at 4.15 mbps.

I have gone into my internet settings, and made sure that my Quality of Service both had no restriction and gave gaming data priority over all other data sent.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I am experiencing these small ping spikes and how I might reduce them further?

Comment: don't stream to twitch if you don't want an increase in ping. You're using some of your bandwidth to upload video, it's going to affect your game. Try lowering the quality of your stream.

Comment: Expecting higher latency is par for the course; you're using more bandwidth, so it makes sense there will be a greater delay.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's anything you can do about that - it's basically just cause and effect of streaming (and is 60 ping really that bad? I mean come on, I play with 130-150 and it's still completely playable. Of course optimal is as close to 0 as possible, but you have to draw a line somewhere to be realistic).

Comment: Bad ping is not an automatic consequence of streaming. There are people that stream LoL in 1080p and have less than 10 ping, so there must be a sufficiently strong internet connection and possibly a specific setup and closeness to their respective server that allows them to do that.

Comment: 34-60 is optimal, ping isn't noticeable enough until 100+, I have large experience in streaming and working in netowork. You shouldn't see/feel anything at 64.

Answer (score 1):

The common ground i saw/heard from a lot of streamers is to split up streaming and playing to different PCs and give the gaming pc priority in your router.

1. The game uses a low amount of data but needs fast replies for your ping so priority there.
2. The streaming processes large amount of data but considering you have a buffer the speed of the data coming through doesnt matter that much.

Comment: You don't need 2 pcs to set a router Quality of service. It can be done with specific application.